# Calculate number of table needed and remaining guest seats - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm really stuck on this task; i'm still learning JavaScript objects so not my ideal question:

> We need to figure out how many tables we need! The number of guests
> may not divide evenly by the number of seats, so we will have to add
> some extra chairs to a few of the tables for them.
>
> The function calculateTables takes two arguments, the number of guests
> and the number of seats around a table.
>
> It should return an object with two properties: a key of tables with
> the value of the number tables, and a key of remainingGuests with a
> value of the number of guests without a seat who will need to be added
> to one of the other tables.

Example log we shoudl try:

> ```
> calculateTables(4, 2);
> // should return { tables: 2 , remainingGuests: 0 }
>
> calculateTables(14, 6);
> // should return { tables: 2 , remainingGuests: 2 }
>
> calculateTables(26, 5);
> // should return { tables: 5 , remainingGuests: 1 }
> ```

My code so far and i'm so stuck.....not sure where to go in solving this question. Any advice will be good:

```
function calculateTables(guests, seats) {
    // Your code goes here...
    
    let tables = 0;
    let remainingGuests = 0;

 for(let i=0; i<guests.length; i++){
if(guests % seats == 0){
tables = guests[i]

}

 }
    
    let obj ={'tables': tables, 'remainingGuests': remainingGuests}

    return obj
    }
```

Comment: `guests` is a plain number, not an array, so it doesn't have a `.length`, and no `[i]` either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, i think it's accurate to your expected result.

```js
function calculateTables (guests, seats) {
    // Define Variable
    let tables = 0;
    let remainingGuests = 0;
    
    // First Validation is guests and seats must greater than 0
    if(guests > 0 && seats > 0) {
        // Check if total guests are greater than or equal from seats
        if(guests >= seats) {
           // Divide guests by seats
           let devideGuests = guests/seats;
    
           // Floor your devided calculation for total tables
           tables = Math.floor(devideGuests);
    
           // Multiply your calculated tables by seat before subtracting it to total guest
           const seatedGuests = tables * seats;
           remainingGuests = guests - seatedGuests;
        } else {
           //If seats are greater
           tables = guests;
        }
    }
    
    // Return your expected object
    return {
        tables,
        remainingGuests
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you..yes it does work. Now i need to go through and understand it. No pint copying if i dont understand it. Thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

Am I overlooking something? This is just straight up division and [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo). The only catch I can see is that JS doesn't have integer division, so you need to `floor`:

```
function calculateTables(guests, seats) {
    return { 
        tables: Math.floor(guests / seats),
        remaingingGuests: guests % seats
    };
}
```

Comment: No, you're not… (other than `(guests - remainingGuests) / seats` to avoid the "need" for `floor`)